# How to make Gattling execute scenario in single thread / in serial

Tags: gatling

I've got a Gatling scenario that I want to run 100,000 times in serial. I don't want concurrent user sessions simulated or any rest periods between invocations of the scenario. I just want it to run a single thread as fast as possible in a loop. I thought I had this figured out with:

```
setup(myTest.splitUsers(100000) into atOnceUsers(1) separatedBy(0 seconds))
```

But this seems to attempt all 100,000 requests in parallel which is obviously not what I want.

My scenario is just a simple HTTP PUT. This isn't much different than curl called a loop, except for Gatling's fantastic reporting. I'm looking for metrics such as requests/sec, response time, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Repeat your scenario for 100,000 times and inject a single user.

```
val myScenario = scenario("my scenario").repeat(100000) {
    //exec()...
}

setUp(myScenario.inject(atOnceUsers(1)))
   //assertions..
```